# Netlogo Variable Scope with Let

Tags: if-statement, scope

General CS question because I was surprised by behavior of `let` in Netlogo.

If I declare a variable from within an if statement per below, is it common for the scope of that variable to be limited to that if statement?

I thought scope generally referred to functions rather than constructs like a loop or if statement. How common is that?

```
if x > y :
     int i = 2
else:
     int i = 3

print(i)

would return: "error: (i) does not exist"
```

Answer (score 2):

I´m not sure, if this answers your question, but the Netlogo Programming Guide on local variables, created with `let`, states:

> Local variables
>
> A local variable is defined and used only in the context of a
>   particular procedure or part of a procedure. To create a local
>   variable, use the let command. If you use let at the top of a
>   procedure, the variable will exist throughout the procedure. If you
>   use it inside a set of square brackets, for example inside an “ask”,
>   then it will exist only inside those brackets.

```
to swap-colors [turtle1 turtle2]
  let temp [color] of turtle1
  ask turtle1 [ set color [color] of turtle2 ]
  ask turtle2 [ set color temp ]
end
```

The same is true if a local variables is created within an `if` or `ifelse` statement. Therefore if you want to use the variable later on, than  declare it before and outside the `ifelse` statement with `let`. Than assign the value with `set` within the `ifelse` statement.

Comment: yeah, that info for netlogo was the origin of the question, I'm not aware of other languages that scope variables to within an if statement, rather scope is defined at the function level, which is why i didn't tag the question with [netlogo] its more general CS than language specific.

Comment: I probably should read your questions more attentively before spitting out answers. Never mind..